# Is there any scientific instrument right now to monitor complicated chemical reaction between atom?

Tags: physical-chemistry

What is some differnt way to use any scientific instrument right now to monitor complicated chemical reaction between atom??

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "monitor"? I'm guess that you are asking about detailed measurements of electron cloud behavior and nuclear separation as a function of time. If so you may want to think about how the measurement might affect the things that you are trying to observe...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I understand your question correctly, one example is [femtosecond laser spectroscopy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultrafast_laser_spectroscopy). A typical application would be to use a light pulse to start a photoreaction then send a second pulse after some time $t$ to measure the optical absoption by the reacting materials. By varying the time delay of the second pulse you can measure the concentrations of the reagents, products and intermediates as a function of time.

If you mean tracking the positions of the reacting atoms then I think it would be hard to do this without perturbing the system.